# In jQuery i cant find out how to change attr again and again

Tags: jquery

Ι can't find how when I get click into the circle to change the attr again and again.for those two attr. I'm new to code obviously!Thank you all for the quick responce.

```
<body>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5SgyFaBS7WI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <div id="circle"></div>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("#circle").click(function() {

            $("iframe").attr("src", <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0WazFtJSIHk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>, function("src","https://www.youtube.com/embed/5SgyFaBS7WI");

        });



    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Your value for `attr` should be enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: You apparently don’t now even the most basic JavaScript syntax yet, otherwise you would have to know that this code as shown is utter nonsense.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the javascript debug console?

Comment: For reference: http://api.jquery.com/attr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5SgyFaBS7WI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<div id="circle">Click me</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var links = [
            "https://www.youtube.com/embed/0WazFtJSIHk",
            "https://www.youtube.com/embed/5SgyFaBS7WI"
        ];

        var counter = 0;

        $("#circle").click(function() {
            $("iframe").attr("src", links[counter % links.length]);
            counter++;
        });
      });

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: @AlexanderBolzhatov precisely, `links[counter % 2]` should be `links[counter % links.length]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.

```
jQuery('iframe').attr('src', 'http://www.youtube.com/...');
```

Add only youtube URL, not entire HTML code.